# Set correct timer for slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to this and can't find a way to do it.
I have 4 images but can't set a rule that moves changes correctly that slideshow image.
Example: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4, if I go from 1 and click to go to 3, timer makes me go to 2 because it was in 1.

```js
onload = start;
function start(){ 
    var i = 1;
    function Move(){  
        i = (i%4)+1;
        document.getElementById('i'+i).checked = true;
    }
    setInterval(Move,10000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the current element index out of the `start` function and change it when you select an element manually:

```js
onload = start;
var currIndex = 1;
function start() {  
    function Move(){    
        currIndex = (currIndex % 4) + 1;
        document.getElementById('i' + currIndex).checked = true;
    }
    setInterval(Move,10000);
}

// better add a class here for simpler selector
document.querySelectorAll('#i1, #i2, #i3, #i4').addEventListener('whatever-event-you-get-on-selection', function() {
    currIndex = yourSelectedId; // use data attributes or something for easier index extraction
});
```